# winehq-stable : Depende: wine-stable (= 9.0.0.0~bullseye-1) E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, wine, dependencies

spreen@juanamanso:~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
winehq-stable : Depende: wine-stable (= 9.0.0.0~bullseye-1)
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.

Comment: Bullseye is Debian and so off topic on Ask Ubuntu. This is an English only site.

Comment: Your about Debian question is off topic but the duplicate links might solve the same problem on Debian too because the winehq-stable package is provided by a PPA.